# SharePoint Profile Lookup

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Question is not on StackOverflow because I am not a developer and hope there is a way to do this without code :)

In SharePoint 2007, is it possible to have a list column do a lookup against a SharePoint Profile?

I would like to be able to create a list with a Person/Group column, and then once I add a user, have the list autopopulate a few columns (such as Manager) pulled from that user’s profile in SharePoint.  Is that something that can be done OOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is not a "List" in the normal SharePoint sense of things that stores all the users.

There is not a webservice call that will get all the profiles in one hit either, so something would need to be programmed.

Comment: Also, if you are looking for the non-OOB solution, I believe it is to create an Event Handler that fires when the item is saved. It can pull the data from the person/group column and automatically populate text columns with the manager/etc. that you need.